# Error debugging with Gradle and JavaFX (NOT M1 CHIP)

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I have a Lenovo with Intel. When run `JavaFX` with gradle works great. But when debug does not execute, get error at first. The error is:

> ```
> Exception has occurred: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
> "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library:
> /home/---/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.openjfx/javafx-graphics/---/---/libprism_es2.so"
> ```

I am using gradle `plugin id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin'` version `'0.0.14'`, `javafx version 20`, and `openjdk 17.0.6`.

My OS is Linux fedora 6.2.15-200.fc37.x86_64

Comment: Linux fedora 6.2.15-200.fc37.x86_64

Comment: Is there a `.so` file in the location it is looking for one?

Comment: I don't know much gradle, so probably can't help much.   I don't even understand why it is looking for a `.so` file.  Gradle uses maven repositories and the javafx jars in maven central stored as os architecture classified artifacts are modules that include the native code, so there wouldn't seem a need for a gradle build to look for a JavaFX `.so` file, especially in a really weird location like that.

Comment: For help, you probably need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: The error can be a misconfigured vscode gradle extension?

Comment: The only file inside that folder is javafx-graphics-20-linux.jar

Comment: I don’t know about vscode, I don’t use it.  But you could run gradle from the command line to verify that it works independently of vscode.  My guess is that the `so` is inside the jar and that is confusing your particular runtime setup, though I could not tell you why nor how to fix it.  If you suspect the IDE config and are stuck, you could switch IDEs, e.g. to Idea community (run the new JavaFX project wizard in Idea to generate a new working debuggable JavaFX Gradle project then copy your code in, if you want to try that).

Comment: What happens if you run `./gradlew run --debug-jvm` (and connect a debugger) manually?

Comment: That works... Anyway created another project in eclipse without gradle... So many errors with blank project, following oficial docs...